# Smallest neighbourhood characterization in finitely generated spaces

Tags: general-topology

To prove that finitely generated spaces are corecompact, I used the following characterisation of finitely generated topological spaces:

> In a finitely generated topological space every point has a smallest
>   neighbourhood.

Now I was wondering how to prove this characterisation. The definition I use for finitely generated topological spaces is the following:

> $\forall A \in \mathcal{P}(X), \forall x \in X: x \in cl(A) \Rightarrow \exists a \in A, x \in cl\{a\}$

I tried proving it by contradiction: Assume that there is no such thing as a smallest neighbourhood. Suppose that $\forall V \in \mathcal{V}(x) \exists W \in \mathcal{V}(x); W \subseteq V$.
Can someone give me a hint so I can come to a contradiction? Or is there a nicer way to prove this?

As always, any hints or comments will be appreciated!

Comment: I personally found your definition of a finite generated topological space hard to comprehend, so perhaps others may as well. For our benefit, I digested it down to this (please correct me if I am wrong): If $A$ is a subset of $X$ and $x\in X$, then $x\in \bar{A}$ implies that $A \cap U \neq \emptyset  $ for all open neighbourhoods $U$ of $x$.

Comment: And now that I've written that out, it appears that is nothing more than what it means for $x$ to be in the closure of $A.$

Comment: @RagibZaman: There is no point $x$ in $(0,1)$ such that $0$ is in the closure of $\{x\}$.

Comment: @Michael Greinecker, Thanks. Could you please point out my error in this then?: 1) By definition of closure, $x$ in the closure of $\{a\}$ means every neighbourhood U of $x$ has non-empty intersection with $\{ a \}.$ 2) U has non-empty intersection with $ \{ a \} $ if and only if $a \in U.$ 3) To say "There exists $a \in A$ such that $x \in \text{cl} \{ a \}  $ is thus equivalent to " $ A \cap U $ is non-empty".

Comment: @RagibZaman In (3) above, the element of $A \cap U$ may vary with $U$. For $x \in \mathrm{cl}\{a\}$ we need $a \in U$ for every $U$.

Comment: @RagibZaman: There are two directions. If every neighborhood of $x$ contains $a\in A$, $x$ is indeed in the closure of $A$. But if $x$ is in the closure of $A$, you only know that every neighborhood of $x$ contains *some* element of $A$, not necessarily the same one.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker, martini. Thanks for pointing that out! So it really should be this?: If $A \subseteq X, x\in X$ then $x\in \bar{A}$ implies that there exists an element $a\in A$ such that for every open neighbourhood $U$ of $x$, $a\in U.$

Comment: @RagibZaman: Yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $U$ be the intersection of all neighborhoods of $x$. We show that $U$ is open. Let $y$ be in the closure of $X\backslash U$. We have to show that $y\in X\backslash U$. By assumption, there is $z\in X\backslash U$ such that $y$ is in the closure of $\{z\}$. Now by construction of $U$, there is an open neighborhood $V$ of $x$ such that $z\notin V$. Since $V$ is open, the closure of $\{z\}$ is not in $V$ and hence $y\notin V$. Hence $y\notin U$ and $y\in X\backslash U$.

Comment: This proof method also proves the stronger statement that in finite generated spaces, arbitrary intersections of open sets are open.

Answer (score 1):

If you show that, in a finitely generated space, any intersection of open sets is open, then it is easy to see that every point $x$ has a smallest neighborhood - it is the intersection of all open sets containing $x$.

In fact, the claim that *intersection of any system of open sets is open* is a characterization of finitely-generated spaces, see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finitely_generated_space).

However, let us have a look only at the direction important for you: You want to show that any finitely-generated space (according to your definition) has this property. This is equivalent to showing that arbitrary union of closed sets is closed.

Let $F=\bigcup_{i\in I}F_i$. Let $x\in\overline{F}$, then there is an $a\in F$ such that $x\in\overline{\{a\}}$. This implies the existence of an $i\in I$ such that $x\in\overline F_i=F_i$ (we take $i\in I$ for which $a\in F_i$). Clearly, this implies $x\in F$. We have shown that $F$ is closed.